# AR/VR Toolkit How to create a scene of the active 3D view?

Tags: autodesk-forge

I have a Model with multiple 3D Views.
With the extension "Viewing.Extension.ViewableSelector" i can switch between the different views.

Each view represents a different building condition which i would like to visualize in AR.
When I create a scene from the model with the AR/VR toolkit only the visible part of the {3D} view is selected by default.

Is there a way to create a scene only from the selected view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When creating a scene in the AR/VR Toolkit, you can specify `view_id` that you'd like to include in the scene: https://app.swaggerhub.com/apis/cyrillef/forge-ar_kit/1.2.1#/ARVR-Toolkit/create_scene.

[image: View ID parameter]

Comment: I didnt see that. I just used bucketKey, objektKey and URN for the project definition. I added view_id and its working fine. You guyes are great! Thank you!

Comment: Glad we could help :) Cheers!